Probability of $Y+b > X$ for iid normal variables conditioned on a rare event
I am thinking of the (imprecise) claim that a small increase in the average ability in a population results in a large increase in the ability of the exceptionally able.
So I'm considering two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$, both normally distributed $N(0,\sigma^2)$ (same $\sigma$ for both), and my general curiosity is to compare the distributions of $X$ and $Y+b$ conditioned on $X\geq c$ and $Y\geq c$ (here $b$ and $c$ are positive constants).
For example, what happens if we keep $b$ constant and take $c$ to infinity?
For example of the example, what can we say about
$p_{b,c}=P(Y+b > X \mid X\geq c,Y\geq c)$?
If the imprecise claim is true, I expect $p_{b,c}$ to increase for a fixed $b$ as $c$ increases. Does it increase? At what rate?
I've made it into a precise question about comparing $X$ and $Y+b$ conditioned on $X\geq c$ and $Y\geq c$. But if there's anything else that's interesting to know about this situation I'll be glad to know.

I don't know much about it at all but I think your question might be related to the concept of robustness. For example, if there is an extreme change in the value of an observation in the population ( a typo for example), then  the median of the population stays the same but the mean changes a lot. One quantifies this by using the concept of breakdown point.  Anyway, this is only an attempt to statistical-ize what your question could be related to since you said that you would be glad to know.

You can improve the question by adding some numerical studies.


This is unrelated to statistical robustness which is concerned with ignoring outliers. 2. The calculation you are doing will depend a lot on the tail of the distribution; any result would depend on the shape of the tail. 3. I'm not sure how this calculation corresponds to "a small increase in the average ability in a population results in a large increase in the ability of the exceptionally able."


@GuillaumeDehaene "Robustness" of a statistical model can refer to its distributional robustness, which is why my answer bothered to show precisely how $\lim_{c\to\infty}p_{b,c}$ depends on the "tail behavior" you mention. (I focused on the OP's purely mathematical question, disregarding its interpretation.)

@GuillaumeDehaene: The small increase in the average ability is an increase by $b$. I am looking at two normal distributions with the same standard deviation, but with means $0$ and $b$. Now, I'm picking an exceptionally able person from each distribution. I'm taking "exceptionally able" to mean at least $c$ above the mean. Now, r.e.s.'s answer shows that taking $c$ very large means that with near certainty, the exceptionally able person from the distribution of $Y+c$ will be more able that the exceptionally able person from the distribution of $X$. Even if $b$ is quite small.

In the previous comment, I meant " ... person from the distribution of $Y+b$ " (not $Y+c$, that was a typo).

Maybe I misunderstand the question, but this seems like it follows if $P(Z > c+b \mid Z > c)$ (for standard normal $Z$) is decreasing in $c$ for fixed $b$. I suspect I either misunderstand something or am oversimplifying something, so I'll think about it some more, but just thought I'd throw this very tentative thought out there.

@BrianTung Per one of the answers at the first link in my answer, we can use that to show $\lim_{c\to\infty}p_{b,c}=1$ (but not monotonicity).  I had that as part of my answer at one time, but switched to using L'Hospital's rule because I wanted to treat also non-normal cases.

(Following is a major revision based on answers I received to a related question.)
Summary

For i.i.d. Normal random variables, $p_{b,c}$ is monotone increasing in $c$, with $\lim\limits_{c\to\infty}p_{b,c}=1$ (proof below).
For i.i.d. non-Normal random variables, $\lim\limits_{c\to\infty}p_{b,c}$ may be any value in the interval $\left[{1\over2},1\right]$ (proof below) and numerical integration indicates that $p_{b,c}$ may be either monotone increasing or decreasing in $c$.

Formula for $\lim_{c\to\infty}p_{b,c}$
In the general case of $X,Y$ i.i.d. with c.d.f $F$ and p.d.f. $f$ , not necessarily Normal, we have (letting $\bar F=1-F$):
$$\begin{align}
p_{b,c}&:=P(Y+b>X\mid X>c,Y>c)\\[1ex]
&=1-P(Y +b<X\mid X>c, Y>c)\\[1ex]
&=1-{P(Y+b<X, X>c, Y>c)\over \bar F(c)^2}\\[1ex]
&=1-{\int_{c+b}^\infty f(x) \int_c^{x-b} f(y)\,dy\, dx \over \bar F(c)^2}\\[1ex]
&=1-{\int_{c+b}^\infty f(x)\left(F(x-b)-F(c)\right)\, dx \over \bar F(c)^2}\\[1ex]
&=1-{\int_{c+b}^\infty f(x) F(x-b)\,dx-\bar F(c+b)F(c) \over \bar F(c)^2}\tag{1}\\[1ex]
\end{align}$$
Therefore, applying the same approach as in @BJM's answer, we have
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{c\to\infty}p_{b,c}&=1-\lim_{c\to\infty}{\int_{c+b}^\infty f(x) F(x-b)\,dx-\bar F(c+b)F(c) \over \bar F(c)^2}\\[1ex]
&=1-\lim_{c\to\infty}{0\cdot 1-f(c+b)F(c) - [-f(c+b)F(c) + \bar F(c+b)f(c)]  \over -2\bar F(c)f(c)}\tag{2}\\[1ex]
&=1-{1\over2}\lim_{c\to\infty}{\bar F(c+b) \over \bar F(c)}\tag{3}\\
&=1-{1\over2}\lim_{c\to\infty}{-f(c+b)\over -f(c)}\tag{4}\\[1ex]
\end{align}$$
where (2) is obtained using L'Hospital's rule, differentiating the integral using Leibniz' integral rule, and (4) is by another application of L'Hospital's rule. Thus,
$$\bbox[10px, border:3px solid lightgrey]{\lim\limits_{c\to\infty}p_{b,c}=1-{1\over2}\lim_{c\to\infty}{f(c+b)\over f(c)}}\tag{5}$$
Examples

If $X,Y$ i.i.d. Normal$(\sigma)$, then $$\lim_{c\to\infty}p_{b,c}=1$$ because
$${f(c+b)\over f(c)}={\exp\left(-{1\over2}{\left({c+b\over\sigma}\right)^2}+{1\over2}{\left({c\over\sigma}\right)^2}\right)}=\exp\left({-2bc-b^2\over2\sigma^2}\right)\to0\ \ \text{as $c\to\infty$}.$$

If $X,Y$ i.i.d. Laplace$(\sigma=\sqrt{2}\,\alpha)$, then $$\lim_{c\to\infty}p_{b,c}=1-{1\over2}\exp\left(-{b\over\alpha}\right)$$ because $${f(c+b)\over f(c)}={\exp\left(-{|c+b|\over\alpha}+{|c|\over\alpha}\right)}=\exp\left(-{b\over\alpha}\right)$$

If $X,Y$ i.i.d. Cauchy$(\sigma=\infty)$, then $$\lim_{c\to\infty}p_{b,c}={1\over2}$$ because $${f(c+b)\over f(c)}={(1+(c+b)^2)^{-1}\over (1+c^2)^{-1}}\to1$$

Here are typical plots for these examples, obtained by numerical integration using Eq.(1) (confirmed also by Monte Carlo simulation):


NB: In general, $p_{b,c}$ can't be less than ${1\over2}$, because the bivariate p.d.f.s are symmetrical in their arguments (i.e. $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$); furthermore, the above three examples suffice show that $\lim_{c\to\infty}p_{b,c}$ may be any value in the interval $\left[{1\over2},1\right]$.

Proof (sketch) that, in the Normal case, $p_{b,c}$ is monotone increasing in $c$
Defining $(\beta,\gamma):=(b/\sigma, c/\sigma),$ and $p(\beta,\gamma):=p_{b/\sigma,c/\sigma},$ we can prove that  ${\partial p(\beta,\gamma) \over \partial \gamma}>0$ for all $c$ by  taking the derivative of Eq.(1) using Leibniz' rule, which reduces to
$${\partial p(\beta,\gamma)\over\partial\gamma}={\phi(\gamma)\over\bar\Phi(\gamma)^2}\left(\bar\Phi(\gamma+\beta)-{2\,I(\beta,\gamma)\over \bar\Phi(\gamma)}\right)\tag{6}
$$
where $\phi$ and $\Phi$ are the standard normal p.d.f and c.d.f., respectively, and
$$I(\beta,\gamma) :=\int_{\gamma+\beta}^\infty\phi(z_1) \int_\gamma^{z_1-\beta}\phi(z_2)\,dz_2\, dz_1 .$$
Therefore, ${\partial p(\beta,\gamma)\over\partial\gamma}>0$ if
$$I(\beta,\gamma) < {1\over2}\,{\bar\Phi(\gamma+\beta)\,\bar\Phi(\gamma)}.\tag{7}
$$
Now (7) is a consequence of the following fact:

If a continuous bivariate distribution has circular symmetry about the origin, then
$$x' \lesseqqgtr y'\implies P(A) \lesseqqgtr P(B)$$
or equivalently,
$$x' \lesseqqgtr y'\implies P(A)\lesseqqgtr{1\over2}P(Q)\implies P(B)\gtreqqless{1\over2}P(Q)$$ where $A$ and $B$ are the upper and lower halves, respectively, of the "shifted quadrant" $Q(x',y'):=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2: x>x', y>y'\}$ bisected by its diagonal through point $(x',y')$.

To apply this, note that  $I(\beta,\gamma)=P(B)$ is the probability of the lower half ($B$) of the shifted quadrant $Q(x'=\gamma+\beta,y'=\gamma)$ bisected by its diagonal. Since $x'=\gamma+\beta>y'=\gamma$, we have the desired result:
$$I(\beta,\gamma)=P(B)< {1\over2}P(Q)={1\over2}{\bar\Phi(\gamma+\beta)\,\bar\Phi(\gamma)} .$$

Thank you so much for taking the time to ask a follow-up question and using it to write this answer. Thank you also for the numerical data. Sorry for taking time to accept. Your answer is incredibly useful to me!

You're welcome. I think the question is interesting, and I'm surprised at being unable (so far) to prove that in the Normal case $p_{b,c}$ is monotone increasing in $c$, though the plots make it seem obvious. (BTW, please note that I just now corrected the plot titles, which had mislabeled the probability.)

I've updated to include a proof that in the Normal case, $p_{b,c}$ is strictly increasing in $c$ for fixed $b$. (In the numerical integration, there is a growing loss of precision as $c$ increases, which is worse for smaller $b$, explaining the very slight downturn visible at $c=5$ in the plot for $b= 0.2$. The plots should probably have been restricted to $0\le c\lessapprox 4$ for that reason.)
